# Can For Loop Do The Work?

Tags: vb6

I have a control array of textboxes and a listbox that contains numbers (ascending order) via inputbox. I need to pick the lowest number and place it to my first control textbox then the proceeding numbers to every second control array of my textbox.

Therefore, List1.List(0) should be placed in Text1(0).text and the List1.List(1) should be placed in Text1(2).text

I can't imagine how to code it so I tried to make a similar scenario in which each number in listbox will be placed in each textbox. Here is my code for my created scenario:

```
For i = 0 to list1.listcount - 1
For j = 0 to text1.count -1
text1(j).text = list1.list(i)
next j
next i
```

But this code always give my textboxes the last number in my listbox.
After hours of spending research in the internet, I found out why this code don't works. But still I can't find any relevance on how to answer my original problem.

What technique should I use? Does using For Loop not the correct way? I've been spending too much time thinking and searching for answer. Someone please help. I am using VB6 because it is the required prgoram to use (even though it is old and many programs are better than this)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
    Text1(i).Text = List1.List(i)
Next i
```

J is not required.

Comment: That would just solved my own generated scenario. My real problem is List1.List(0) should be placed in Text1(0).text and the List1.List(1) should be placed in Text1(2).text then List.List(2) should be placed on Text1(4) and so on until the last item in Listbox

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understanding what you want, but I'll go on your following comment

> My real problem is List1.List(0) should be placed in Text1(0).text and the List1.List(1) should be placed in Text1(2).text then List.List(2) should be placed on Text1(4) and so on until the last item in Listbox

I know it's not the nicest solution, but it would do what you want, well at least from what I understand from your comment. here we go:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
j = 0
For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
    Text1(j).Text = List1.List(i)
    if j = 0 then j = j + 1
    j = j + 2
Next i
```